# Reason why html id attribute is uppercase generated in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I am quite new to ASP.NET.  When creating new pages that already contain ASP.NET components the id attribute is generated in upper case, for other elements the id attribute is generated in lower case:

```
<asp:xxx ID="foo" ...>
  vs.
<div id="blaa" ...>
```

I am wondering what the reason for that is.  I would tend to use lower case in both cases - is that ok?  Can someone please shade some light on this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Since HTML is case insensitive for element and attribute names, does it really matter?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - it depends on the variant of HTML used. Strict XHTML needs to all be in lower case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `<asp:xxx` the attribute names have to match the properties of control class `xxx`.

Microsoft naming convention is that 2 letter acronyms are upper case, so the property name is `ID`.

Any other property name longer than 2 letters will be CamelCase.

The server will parse the `<asp:xxx` tag, so the result HTML might look very different.

Alternatively `<div` is HTML and will be all lowercase. The server will just serve it up as it is in your page.

Comment: So this is just a conventional thing that in the asp:xxx case 'ID' will be upper case but technically I could use lower case as well?

Comment: @Andreas Fluegge - sort of, for instance `<asp:ListBox` represents a `ListBox` class. Microsoft's naming convention is applied to all the class's properties, so you get `ListBox.ID` as the property name and  `<asp:ListBox ID=` as the WebForm mapping. The WebForm mapping is case-insensitive, but Visual Studio will apply intellisense and auto correction, so you can type lowercase property names but it's messy to keep them. Just bear in mind that `<asp:xxx` is *not* HTML, it's just a placemarker like `{0}` would be in a format string.

Comment: Actually Identifier is one word so id is an abbreviation and according to microsoft convention should be written as Id and not ID. While data base is a two word term so its acronym will be written as DB.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @RonenFestinger they make exceptions for ID and OK specifically, unless in a Pascal cased identifier. All MS's web forms components have `ID` as the class's property and so the same case on the pseudo HTML attribute.

Comment: @Keith In the link I posted they say ID should be written as Id: "Note
The two abbreviations that can be used in identifiers are ID and OK. In Pascal-cased identifiers they should appear as Id, and Ok. If used as the first word in a camel-cased identifier, they should appear as id and ok, respectively."

Comment: @RonenFestinger yes, so MS (in their own code) tend to do `ComponentName.ID` (identifier), `ComponentName.RelatedId` (Pascal-cased) and `ComponentName.Action(int idForAction)` (camel-cased prefix).

Comment: @RonenFestinger The wording of that quote is a little confusing, but you can look at what convention MS actually follow in their own code for clarification. All their current ASP forms components are `ID` (for instance `ListBox.ID`) and none of their components are `Component.Id`.

Comment: @keith I know they use ID instead of Id in asp controls. I don't know why, same question as the one who asked here. The camel case you showed is ok because arguments to functions always start with lower case.

Answer (score 0):

That is just the ASP.NET syntax of Visual Studio changing to be uppercase.  When you look at the actual generated HTML it will be lowercase just like the rest of your HTML.

You can do either, but the "Auto Generated" stuff or auto corrected stuff will have ID.