# Unable to use html controls from code behind

Tags: html

I am using html tags and I have written some code on code behind but it is not picking the values given to id. Infact it says the 'FileUpload1' does not exist in the current context. I do not want to use asp controls at all. I have heard adding runat = "server" does the thing but still cannot find the id's. What am I doing wrong?

```
      <div id="mainContent">
  <div class="column" id="colFull">
        <div class="contentSection">
            <div id="progress" style="display: none">
                <img alt="Loading .." src="../../../Images/ajax.gif" />
            </div>



                                     <table width="100%">
                                           <tr>
                                                <td class="label" style="width:15%">
                                                   Upload File
                                                </td>
                                                <td class="description" >
                                                    <input type="file" id="FileUpload1" runat="server" 
                  class="largeTextField"  onclick="Upload"  multiple="multiple" 
                     style="width:260px;"/>
                                                    <input type="button" id="btnUpload" 
          runat="server" value="Upload"  />
                                                </td>

                                            </tr>
                                           </table>
```

mycodebehind:

```
       public partial class PgPracFileUploader : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        string contentType = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;
        using (Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream)
        {
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
            {
                byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
                string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    string query = "insert into tblFiles values (@Name, @ContentType, @Data)";
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", filename);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentType", contentType);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", bytes);
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }
}
```

It says FileUpload1 does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Typo: it should be `FieUpload1` not `Fileupload1`

Comment: I have the correct id's in my code. It still gives me error

Comment: Update the question!

Comment: I am asking about -- `<input type="file" id="FileUpload1" runat="server" 
                  class="largeTextField"  onclick="Upload"  multiple="multiple" 
                     style="width:260px;"/>`

Comment: What about it? Updated the question

Comment: My id is FileUpload1 and my code behind is not picking this id. Am i missing somehting?

Answer (score 3):

Try to change:

```
<input type="file" id="FieUpload1" runat="server" class="largeTextField"  onclick="Upload" multiple="multiple" style="width:260px;"/>
```

to

```
                 Id Must be same as you are using in the .cs page
                         \/\/\/\/
 <input type="file" ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" class="largeTextField"  onclick="Upload" multiple="multiple" style="width:260px;"/>
```

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988749/reason-why-html-id-attribute-is-uppercase-generated-in-asp-net) your `id` attribute is case sensitive so you are using `id` then the server will just serve it up as it is in your page, but if you used `ID` then the server will be serve that control as a asp.net control.

Comment: Yes my id's are same. Sorry. I made a typo mistake in my question

Comment: Okay then just try above line and check

Comment: @Unknown I think the problem is related to `id` or `ID`. You typed `id` but as asp.net looking for `ID`. Can you cross check this?

Comment: @Unknown that code which should run on initial page load - like filling dropdownn values etc.